# WP7 Listbox how to show load more item

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, virtualizingstackpanel

I know that the Windows Phone 7 ListBox use `VirtualizingStackPanel` by default to optimize memory.

However, when I add more items to the view model, the listbox doesnot show those new items. I must scroll up, then down to see them.

My view model does implement `IList`

Many articles around have this problem, like [this guide](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/04/06/wp7-how-to-extend-listbox-when-reaching-last-item.aspx)

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does you viewmodel implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) interface and raise the PropertyChanged event when you've added more items?

A better solution is to make the viewmodel property you bind against an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This class will automatically raise the PropertyChanged event when items are added/removed from the collection.

Comment: I 've already used INotifyPropertyChanged, I heard that load more item break virtualizing, how can we fix that ?

Comment: You can handle the CleanUpVirtualizedItemEvent (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.cleanupvirtualizeditemevent(v=vs.95).aspx) and Cancel the re-virtualization. You might also want to look at setting the VirtualizationMode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.virtualizationmode(v=vs.95).aspx) to Recycle.

Comment: why to cancel the re-virtualization? how to cancel? If I add more item to my viewmodel, does listbox keep virtualizing, or break it ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You say you've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. Did it work as expected when adding new items, without have to scroll up, then down when adding items and raising the PropertyChanged event? And you're just worried that virtualization isn't working properly?

Comment: when I used ObservableCollection as binding source, add add more items to this collection, I see that memory consumed increased, which mean UI virtualizing is not working. So I creat  a class that implements IList and INotifyPropertyChanged, memory is not high as before, but I must scroll up, then down to see new items :(

Comment: When you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, did you remember to call the PropertyChanged event (with the correct property name) after adding the new items to the list? Also, are you sure the increased memory usage is related to missing virtualization and not that you're adding more items to the list etc.?